# JRE client upgrade impacts on GWT application usage

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gwt, upgrade, smartgwt

I will upgrade the JRE of my clients workstations from JRE6 to JRE7. 
They will need to access a server application that exposes a website written with Smart GWT.
There is no planned upgrade on the server side.

Should I worry about any impact on the client side for using my Smart GWT application?

Edit: my guess is that GWT runs java script, which is handled by the browser and not the JRE, so there is no impact. But I'd like to find some source references for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not develop your application on those machines, but simply "use it", they don't even need a JRE installed.

As you guessed, *in the end*, everything served to the browser is javascript, media and not much more; nothing related to (a particular) JRE proper. At least from a GWT standpoint: if you use some java tech (applets?) that can affect your clients through your app, well, this is a different matter.

And no official reference can beat looking into your application's war folder :)

Comment: There is no applet, just straight SmartGWT. I continued to read on it and all I see is that everything done on the server side that is for the client is transformed in JavaScript. So no impact with the client JVM. Thanks!